# Interchange Letters From String in Assembly Language 8086

Tags: assembly, ascii, dos, x86-16

I have a very simple problem that i need to achieve. First you enter a string, the first output should copy the last letter of the string and replace the first letter of the string and then the last letter should be replace with the first letter.
The second output should capitalize the first letter of the string. I've already did the second output, my problem now is the first output. Please see the expected result below.

**Expected Result**

```
Enter string: jon jones
son jonej
Jon jones
```

**Current Code**

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA        
    INPUT_STRING          DB 10,13,"Enter string: $"    
    USER_INPUT_STRING     DB 80 DUP('$') 
    BREAKLINE             DB 10, 13, "$" 
.CODE
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX  

    LEA DX,INPUT_STRING
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, USER_INPUT_STRING
    MOV AH, 0AH
    INT 21H  

    LEA DX, BREAKLINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H  

    SUB USER_INPUT_STRING + 2, 32       ;Capitalize
    MOV AH, 02H
    INT 21H 

    LEA DX, BREAKLINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H  

    LEA DX, USER_INPUT_STRING + 2       ;Output of capitalize
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, BREAKLINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H       

    MOV AH, 4CH
    INT 21H
END
```

**allowed commands**

```
mov, lea, int, inc, dec, add, sub, proc, re, db
```

Comment: @MichaelPetch. MASM

Comment: Yeah im using emu8086

Comment: Sorry for that. No. Im using emu8086

Comment: @MichaelPetch. Thats the exact question that was asked. You were to enter a string then output the the interchange of letters and the capitalize the first letter

Comment: @MichaelPetch. We were just given a program to solve. This is the given program.  Enter string: jon jones
son jonej
Jon jones.   Also the allowed commands are mov, lea, int, inc, dec, add, sub, proc, re, db.

Comment: @MichaelPetch. We were just started learning assembly so advance commands should not be used for now. Thats the only commands that is allowed to use for now

Comment: @MichaelPetch. The question was written on board. So i copied it. The question is truly the question i have attached above

Comment: @MichaelPetch. No you cant use [] for now

Comment: @MichaelPetch. But it does said to us verbally

Comment: @MichaelPetch. I assure that these are the only restrictions. In the future we can use []

Comment: Where did it say you could use `DUP`?

Comment: Your code doesn't even follow the rules that are being claimed were given to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buffer of [`Int 21/AH=0Ah`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm) has three parts: size, length, string. The size is the maximal size of the string and **must** be initialized.

Change

```
USER_INPUT_STRING     DB 80 DUP('$')
```

to

```
USER_INPUT_STRING     DB 80, 0, 80 DUP('$')
```

Consider, that the string starts at `USER_INPUT_STRING + 2`. There is its first character. After you have entered the string, you will find the length of the string you have entered at `USER_INPUT_STRING + 1`, in this case `09h`. So, you'll find the last character of the entered string at `USER_INPUT_STRING + 2 + (9 - 1)`. Use registers to swap the values at those memory addresses:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    INPUT_STRING          DB 13,10,"Enter string: $"
    USER_INPUT_STRING     DB 80, 0, 80 DUP('$')
    BREAKLINE             DB 13, 10, "$"
.CODE
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    LEA DX,INPUT_STRING
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, USER_INPUT_STRING
    MOV AH, 0AH
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, BREAKLINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    MOV AL, USER_INPUT_STRING + 2
    XOR CX, CX
    MOV CL, USER_INPUT_STRING + 1
    MOV BX, OFFSET USER_INPUT_STRING + 2
    ADD BX, CX
    DEC BX
    MOV AH, [BX]
    MOV [BX], AL
    MOV USER_INPUT_STRING + 2, AH

    LEA DX, USER_INPUT_STRING + 2
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, BREAKLINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    MOV AX, 4C00H
    INT 21H
END
```

The only way to avoid the square brackets, I see in the use of `LODSB` and `MOVSB`:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H

.DATA
    INPUT_STRING          DB 13,10,"Enter string: $"
    USER_INPUT_STRING     DB 80, 0, 80 DUP('$')
    BREAKLINE             DB 13, 10, "$"

.CODE
main PROC
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX

    LEA DX,INPUT_STRING
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, USER_INPUT_STRING
    MOV AH, 0AH
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, BREAKLINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    CALL swap

    LEA DX, USER_INPUT_STRING + 2
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, BREAKLINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    MOV AX, 4C00H
    INT 21H
main ENDP

swap PROC
    LEA DI, USER_INPUT_STRING + 2
    MOV AL, USER_INPUT_STRING + 1
    MOV AH, 0
    SUB AL, 1
    ADD DI, AX
    MOV SI, DI
    LODSB
    MOV AH, USER_INPUT_STRING + 2
    XCHG AL, AH
    STOSB
    MOV USER_INPUT_STRING + 2, AH
    RET
swap ENDP

END main
```

In EMU8086 and in TASM (**not** in MASM) you can also use the special preprocessor arithmetic: `USER_INPUT_STRING + 2 + BX - 1`:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H

.DATA
    INPUT_STRING          DB 13,10,"Enter string: $"
    USER_INPUT_STRING     DB 80, 0, 80 DUP('$')
    BREAKLINE             DB 13, 10, "$"

.CODE
main PROC
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX

    LEA DX,INPUT_STRING
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, USER_INPUT_STRING
    MOV AH, 0AH
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, BREAKLINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    CALL swap

    LEA DX, USER_INPUT_STRING + 2
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    LEA DX, BREAKLINE
    MOV AH, 09H
    INT 21H

    MOV AX, 4C00H
    INT 21H
main ENDP

swap PROC
    MOV AH, USER_INPUT_STRING + 2
    MOV BL, USER_INPUT_STRING + 1
    MOV BH, 0
    MOV AL, USER_INPUT_STRING + 2 + BX - 1
    MOV USER_INPUT_STRING + 2, AL
    MOV USER_INPUT_STRING + 2 + BX - 1, AH
    RET
swap ENDP

END main
```

All programs change the content of the string. To undo this, you have to `call swap` a second time. It is up to you to incorporate the second part.

Comment: You can simplify this by using an addressing mode like `[BX-1]` instead of `dec bx` first.  Or if you're optimizing for code-size, then set BX to point at the first char first so you can use `[BX-1]` to access the length.   It might be good to comment on what value is in BX at certain steps.

Comment: @rkhb. I'm not allowed to use XOR and [] in [BX]. Can you replace some of your codes? Thanks

Comment: @Joseph: If you have ridiculous arbitrary restrictions, put them in the question.  `xor cx,cx` is just zeroing CX, so loading CL will zero-extend the value into CX.  You can zero CX any way you want, e.g. `sub cx,cx` or `mov cx,0`.  As for BX vs. other registers, you need an addressing mode with a register in it to address the end of the string.  So pick a different one if you don't want to use BX.

Comment: @PeterCordes. I'm sorry just the [] in [BX].

Comment: @rkhb. one more thing, you forgot about the capitalize, you removed it. Maybe you can use PROC for this. Thank a lot rkhb

Comment: @Joseph: you have to use `[]` for indirect addressing modes with an address in a register.  It's a required part of MASM-style syntax.  The only way I could think of to avoid this would be self-modifying code, or fully unrolling a loop that has every possible position in the array hard-coded into an addressing mode like `mov al, USER_INPUT_STRING + 24`, and you conditionally jump over all the ones that don't match.

Comment: @PeterCordes and rkhb. Oh ok. You cant also use a loop by the way. Thanks guys. Sorry again for my noobness just started learning assembly

Comment: @rkhb: this answer looks fine to me.  It seems like the OP wants you to format it into a form that they can hand in for their homework assignment.  Restoring the first char to lower-case after printing after the first modification seems totally fine to leave up to them, or something you can mention in text.  TL:DR: don't enable people to behave like a help vampire.

Comment: @Joseph: A fully-unrolled loop isn't actually a loop anymore, it's just the loop body repeated 80 times, with different hard-coded offsets for each one.  If you really want that, you can make this work without using `[]` in your source code.  That's obviously horrible and IDK why you'd want that.

Comment: I think I found a bug in your buffer: you need one more `dup('$')` than the max user input length, because you want it to be *still* $-terminated even if the DOS function fills the amount of space you tell it about.  I posted an answer that is far fewer instructions for the "real work", but ended up more complicated than yours because that was more fun.

Comment: Oh good idea with `lodsb` / `stosb` to work around the syntax restriction!  I forgot about implicit addressing when making absolute statements in earlier comments. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes: In any case, there is a "$" at BREAKLINE. For the treatment of the superfluous 0Dh - if that has been noticed so far - I'm waiting for a new question - if anyone is still seriously programming DOS.

Comment: @rkhb Is it possible not to use lodsb, xchg and stosb? Im not allowed to use these. One more command other than you used that is allowed is the inc and dec. Thank you

Comment: @rkhb. Sorry this is my fault. I've edited my question with the allowed commands. You also forgot the code that capitalize the string. This one, SUB USER_INPUT_STRING + 2, 32 MOV AH, 02H INT 21H . This is included in the output also. Thank you

Comment: @Joseph: And a third program. Look at my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun, here's anoptimized version inspired by rkhb's answer.  Somewhere between this and rkhb's would be a simpler version with fewer instructions but without making it hard to follow.

---

**DOS `int 21h / AH=0Ah` takes a pointer to a struct, not just a flat buffer.**  The first 2 bytes are a buffer-size and length.  (The DOS function stores the length instead of returning it in AL for some reason).  Documentation: http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#dosbuf

You should make your buffer *larger* than the max length you specify so it's still `$`-terminated after a max-length input.  Apparently a CR is left in the buffer after the user input, but not CR LF, and IDK if it's guaranteed if the user input hit the max length instead of ending with the user hitting return.  The input-size left in the buffer by DOS excludes the CR.  Your version using the pre-filled buffer of `$` will end up printing CR CR LF because it uses the terminator, not the length, but that's probably not a problem for output to the screen.

You can make it another 2 bytes larger than so you have room to append a CRLF yourself, instead of needing to print that with a separate call.  Since you get a length that doesn't include the CR, it's easy to overwrite it and leave just CR LF after the user input, before the first `$`.

---

Optimizations:

First of all, you could make this a `.com` executable so all your segment registers are already set appropriately; use `.model tiny`.  (Except then you're pretty much guaranteed to get a self-modifying-code pipeline stalls from having the data right next to the code.)

You also don't need LEA to put static addresses in registers.  `mov dx, OFFSET INPUT_STRING` is 1 byte shorter.  There's no `[disp8]` addressing mode with no register.

---

After restoring the first character back to lower-case with `add [mem], 20h` or `or [mem], 20h`, you're back to your original situation.  (Assuming that the input character *was* in fact lower case, not originally upper case).

---

You want to load the length so you know where the *last* character is.  You're stuck with 8086 so you can't just use `movzx cx, byte ptr [bx]` to zero-extend it into a 16-bit register; you have to zero a 16-bit register then merge a byte into the low half.  (Or other possibilities).

You're also going to want the pointer in a register at some point, so you might as well do that early (in SI or DI or BX) so you can use more compact addressing modes, or even use `mov dx, bx` instead of mov dx, OFFSET USER_INPUT_STRING`.  Although with addresses only being 16-bit, it's not worth spending extra instructions on that.

Here's the interesting part; starting with reading user input.

```
.DATA
max_user_len = 80           ; assemble time constant, not stored in memory by this line

    ; +3 extra $ chars means we can append a CRLF and *still* have it $-terminated
    ; after a max-length user input
    input_buf             DB max_user_len, 0,  max_user_len+3 DUP('$')
 ; notice that the end of the buffer is far below 256 bytes into the .data segment
 ; which makes address math with 8-bit registers safe.
 ; this is a hack which can break if you link more things together and have a bigger data segment.

    prompt_string         DB 13,10,"Enter string: $"
    BREAKLINE             DB 13, 10, "$"

.CODE
 main:

    ... prompt and stuff same as before
    ; then the interesting part

    mov DX,  OFFSET input_buf
    MOV AH, 0AH                  ; DOS buffered input
    INT 21H

;;; you may need to print a CR LF here, according to Michael Petch's comment
;;; pressing enter doesn't echo the newline

  ;; load from the input
    mov    si,  OFFSET input_buf + 2   ; pointer to first data char
    mov    cx, [si-1]                    ; CL = length,  CH=original first char

  ;; append a CR LF to the end of the buffer.
    mov    bx, si
    add    bl, cl                ; HACK: the whole buffer is in the first 256 bytes of the segment and thus we don't need carry propagation into the high half
     ; BX points to one past the end user input.
    mov  word ptr [bx], 0A0Dh    ; append CR LF = 0D 0A = little-endian 0x0A0D.  Still $-terminated because we have extra padding.

  ;; first output, including a CR LF
                                 ; SI still points at the first char
    and   byte ptr [si], ~20h    ; clear the ASCII-lowercase bit
    mov    dx, si
    mov    ah, 09h
    int    21h                   ; DOS buffered output: printing just the text.

  ;; swap first and last
  ;; We still have the original first char already loaded (CH)
  ;; just need to load the last char and then store both to opposite places.

    mov    al, [bx-1]            ; last char before CR LF $
    mov    [bx-1], ch            ; replace it with orig first char
    mov    [si], al              ; store last char

    ; DX = output buffer, AH = 0Ah  from last time
    ; second output
    int   21h 

    ; exit
    mov   ax, 4c00H
    int   21h

    ret
```

**Untested**, there might be an off-by-1 error in there somewhere.

This is mostly "optimized" for 8086 where code-size is most important.  Otherwise I might copy and modify CH and store that, instead of using a memory destination `and` that will have to reload that byte from cache/memory again.

`xchg [bx-1], ch` would be even smaller, but the implicit `lock` prefix can make it slower.

Comment: Thanks Peter. But its more complicated :)

Comment: If you want to make this a complete DOS COM example (OP is explicitly using EXE though) - add `.model tiny` at the top.  You also need an `org 100h` just after `.CODE`. `buflen+3 DUP('$')` should be `max_user_len+3 DUP('$')`. `and   byte ptr [si], ~20h` is not MASM syntax, it should be `and   byte ptr [si], NOT 20h` . There is no end to your program so I'd consider at a minimum a `ret` at the end.

Comment: One thing your program doesn't account for is that in DOS after you read a string with Int 21h/AH=0Ah the CR is left in the buffer as you say BUT  only a CR is sent to the console leaving the cursor at the beginning of the current line. You will need to at least output a LF before printing the first string to avoid the next string you write appearing over top of the input string on the console.

Comment: Since you are making this a DOS COM program you will also need `END main` at the bottom.  The preferred alternative though is to simply use `END` at the bottom and place the `.STARTUP` directive under `.CODE`. You will have to remove the `org 100h` directive as well. `.STARTUP` will handle setting the ORG to 100h and also set the entry point when using the `tiny` model.

Comment: Seems the OP has clarified they are using EMU8086. It has quirks. It uses `~` unlike MASM that uses `NOT` . As well EMU8086 doesn't move the cursor at all after you hit ENTER when inputting a string. So you will need to send a CR LF to make sure the output of the first string is on the beginning of a new line.

Comment: Your program doesn't exactly answer the question though, as the output you are giving isn't what the question asked.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I wasn't intending this to be the complete program, just showing the interesting part.  Updated with `...` filler for the prompt + startup stuff (whether that's .EXE setting DS or `org 100h` for .com, and putting the data at the end.)  Although actually `org 100h` would break my hack of doing an 8-bit add for the data offset.